# Wiring a transfer switch for a generator

Tags: generator, circuit-breaker

I bought a 12500 W generator and I am shopping for a transfer switch.  My question is this: On my main 200 amp panel I have a 50 amp subpanel  which i would like to wire into the transfer switch. Is there a specific switch I should use? The switch I was considering is the pto tran 2 r510a. It has 6 15 amp and 4 20 amp.

Comment: Are yousaying that the proposed transfer switch has 6 15 amp and 4 20 amp circuits?  I wouldn't expect a transfer switch to have that.

Comment: "*It has 6 15 amp and 4 20 amp.*" What does that mean?

Comment: What make and model of generator did you buy?

Comment: If you already have a subpanel that does what you want, maybe you don't need a transfer switch with a lot of breakers on it. You could maybe just use a simple switch such as the Reliance Controls CSR302. However, that particular switch is only rated for 30 Amps at 240 V.  I guess the question is, how many branch circuits do you need? And how many amps?

Comment: Shock tank, those transfer switches are horribly expensive to purchase and install and very limiting. 
Check out generator breaker lockout kit for your panel. These are way cheaper all the way around and give options like having one load run for a few hours then shut it down and turn another load on, it’s rare for me to install the type you are asking about.

Comment: @EdBeal "interlock" is the word you were probably looking for. :-)

Comment: @greg hill yes I am in the middle of reviewing our lockout procedures for the hospital and hat that on my mind. +

Comment: The generator is Duromax 12500 dual fuel